# Qualtrics language options - show once and store

Tags: survey, qualtrics

I have a qualtrics survey in 2 languages (English/Spanish), but the language option is appearing on all the pages. Is there a way to only have the language option on the first page so that participants don’t switch back and forth from languages? I have checked the qualtrics support groups but so far no luck. They provide some type of Javascript or code but it hasn’t worked so far.